# Serialize List<Object> that property of list item is element name in XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I don't know if the topic is correct, if not please correct. So far i am not sure what to search for my problem so maybe the question has already been answered before.

Currently i have the following class (as example):

```
[Serializable]
public class Sample
{
    public string Something { get; set; }
    public List<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
}


[Serializable]
public class Parameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

This structure i have to serialize to the following XML:

```
<Sample>
   <Something>1234512345112345</Something>  
   <Parameters>
     <Name>Value</Name>
     <Name>Value</Name>
   </Parameters>
 </Sample>
```

So the XML should contain the property value of the attribute "Name" as XML-Element Name.

**Update 20.05.2015**
I have the following XML content:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
 <ProcessData>
 <ID>123456</ID> 
  <IDYTPE>BASEPLATE</IDYTPE> 
  <State>FAIL</State> 
  <Recipe>654321</Recipe> 
 <ProcessDataParameter>
  <test_0>0</test_0> 
  <test_1>12,34</test_1> 
  <test_2>24,68</test_2> 
  <test_3>37,02</test_3> 
  <test_4>49,36</test_4> 
  <test_5>61,7</test_5> 
  </ProcessDataParameter>
  </ProcessData>
```

When i try to use the following code to deserialize:

```
 public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            reader.ReadStartElement("ProcessData");

            this.Id = reader.ReadElementString("ID");
            this.IdType = reader.ReadElementString("IDYTPE");
            this.State = reader.ReadElementString("State");
            this.Recipe = reader.ReadElementString("Recipe");

            reader.ReadStartElement("ProcessDataParameter");
            this.ProcessDataParameter = new List<ProcessDataParameter>();

            var subTree = reader.ReadSubtree();

            while (subTree.Read())
            {
                if (subTree.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                {
                    var nm = subTree.LocalName;
                    //Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = nm, Value = subTree.Value });

                }
            }

            reader.ReadEndElement();

        }
```

Everything gets read out fine expect the process data parameters.

It seems like the subTree.Read() just reades the  element out of the XML content instead of all elements contained in the .

In the while loop the reader goes through the following values (*debuged*)

- test_0 (start tag)
- 0 (value between the tag)
- test_0 (end tag

and then out of the while.
Seems like the reader sees the  as an subtree.
Further only the 0 - value gets recognized as XmlNodeType.Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement [IXmlSerializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and create your own custom serialization behaviour for your `Sample` class. So in your case something like this should work

```
[Serializable]
public class Sample : IXmlSerializable
{
    public string Something { get; set; }
    public List<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(reader);

        Something = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/Sample/Something").FirstChild.Value;

        var parameters = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/Sample/Parameters");
        if (parameters.HasChildNodes)
        {
            Parameters = new List<Parameter>();
            foreach (XmlElement childNode in parameters.ChildNodes)
            {
                Parameters.Add(new Parameter {Name = childNode.LocalName, Value = childNode.FirstChild.Value});
            }
        }
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("Something", this.Something);
        writer.WriteStartElement("Parameters");
        foreach (var parameter in Parameters)
        {
            writer.WriteElementString(parameter.Name, parameter.Value);
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

**Updated to include ReadXml implementation for deserialization**
I'm not quite sure if the ReadXml is complete as I can't test this now, you might have to tweak it a bit for the Parameters

Comment: Great. Looks like that is exactly that what i was looking for. So far i was not able to test it. Does it also work if you get the XML - Content and deserialize it to this object or wouldn't it work?

Comment: Should work @DanielW. . I created my own Sample class just to test and could both serialize and deserialize

Comment: The serialize way works perfectly - but not the deserialize way. After deserialize the xml to object the object is empty (properties are not filled) maybe im missing something?

Comment: Ah, no more like I missed something @DanielW. ... i only tried it with an empty object so that's why it worked. Updating answer...

Comment: I've updated my question. So far it is not working 100% correctly and im still figuring out how to get it work at 100%. Maybe u got an idea

Comment: @DanielW. had a little go there now and can't get it to work properly with the reader. Updated answer to use an XmlDocument instead and it works

Comment: God Damn, i love u! Thanks so much. Seems like i need to spend some hours on the XML topic to get into it!

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Sample sample = new Sample(){
                Something = "1234512345112345",
                Parameters = new List<Parameter>(){
                    new Parameter(){
                        Name = new List<string>(){"Value", "Value"}
                    }
                }
            };

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Sample));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, sample);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Sample));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            Sample newSample = (Sample)xs.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("Sample")]
    public class Sample
    {
        [XmlElement("Something")]
        public string Something { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Parameters")]
        public List<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
    }


    [XmlRoot("Parameters")]
    public class Parameter
    {
        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public List<string> Name { get; set; }
    }
}
​
```